# How to remove a folder recursively?

Tags: recursion, nant

With NAnt script, I'm looking for solution to remove all folder named `.svn` recursively in a given folder.

Using `delete` task just delete one file/folder but not recursively.

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
<delete>
  <fileset defaultexcludes="false" >
    <include name="**/.svn/**" />
  </fileset>
</delete>
```